# Web config transformation fails

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, web.config-transform

We have asp.net web project which we are migrating to .NET SDK-style project with centralized nuget package management.

Template that we are using is `<Project Sdk="MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb/4.0.88">` and we have a Web.Config file with three transformations (Debug, Release, Test). Build Action is set to content, and Copy to Output Directory is set to None.

VS build works just fine, however when we try our release build, we get following message:

```
PreTransformWebConfig:
  Found The following for Config tranformation:
  Web.config, Web.config
  Skip copying Web.config to ...\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\W
  eb.config, File ...\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\Web.config i
  s up to date
```

And build fails with:

```
Transforming Source File: ...\Web.config;Web.config
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publi
shing.targets(1552,5): error : Could not open Source file: Could not find file '...\Web.config;Web.config'. [...Web.API.csproj]
```

Build command:

```
msbuild /p:configuration=release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DebugType=None /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:WarningLevel=0
```

How can I rectify this issue? This is a .net framework project and having ability to transform web.config is quite important for us.

Comment: When you publish from VS does the release config work? (from VS, only debug, and release configs are supported, and ONLY during use of the VS publish option.  So, does publish from VS work? (setup a publish to a local folder - that's the most easy way to test this, since then you can in that local folder check/test/look at/inspect the final web.config produced into that test publish folder. So, does a publish to folder from VS work? (if not, then FOR SURE your command line use of build not going to work).

Comment: VS publish doesn't work either... It succeeds, but output directory is empty. I tried both debug and release configs. Unfortunately, there are no errors, all I get is:  
Build started...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 17 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 9:51 AM and took 00.154 seconds ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish started at 9:51 AM and took 00.154 seconds ==========

Comment: It appears that publish problem is originating from the template that I am using: https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb

I downloaded the source files and example apps also do not publish to folder.

And then I found this thread: https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb/issues/21

Answer (score 1):

This happened when a project was migrated to SDK-style, while keeping the explicit Content items.

Fix: Add `<EnableWebFormsDefaultItems>false</EnableWebFormsDefaultItems>` or remove the explicit items.

Original answer copied from:
https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

In the end we had some mess with CSPROJ file itself... What works for us is:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.Release.config">
      <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.Test.config">
      <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
 .....
<ItemGroup>    
    <Content Update="Web.config">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Web.Debug.config">
        <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
        <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Web.Release.config">
        <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
        <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```